# GUI Wallet never seems to connect (OSX)

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I've tried using a public node as well as a local node, but the wallet never seems to connect.

If I run the GUI via the terminal (`./monero-wallet-gui --daemon-host 127.0.0.1:18080`), I get some log output that matches what I'd expect:

`2017-08-21 13:00:17.307     ERROR   net.http    contrib/epee/include/net/http_client.h:387  HTTP_CLIENT: Failed to SEND
2017-08-21 13:00:27.310     ERROR   net.http    contrib/epee/include/net/http_client.h:441  Unexpected recv fail`

This repeats several times over.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try use `./monero-wallet-gui --daemon-address 127.0.0.1:18080` instead

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 different start-up options:

```
--daemon-address arg                Use daemon instance at <host>:<port>
--daemon-host arg                   Use daemon instance at host <arg> instead
```

You're using the one for hostname so it's expecting `localhost:18080` or similar.

To make it recognize the IP, use the `--daemon-address` option, like:

`./monero-wallet-gui --daemon-address 127.0.0.1:18080`

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to connect the GUI to the P2P port, but the GUI expects to talk to the RPC port. Try this instead:

./monero-wallet-gui --daemon-address 127.0.0.1:18081

Alternatively, just run:

./monero-wallet-gui

since those are the defaults.

This assumes you did not configure monerod to use 18080 as RPC port, and another custom P2P port. While it is *possible*, it is pretty unlikely.